# I have to work with Bisector planes. Can u pls help me?

Tags: solid-geometry

The points are A (1.0, -1) B (2.3.1) C (0.2, -3) Determine point P that’s from the same distance from A, B and C and at a distance √5 from the plane ABC. ![So this is how I solved it , but I have to do something with Bisector planes) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqKCt.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @user755662 I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: Hi thanks I upload it. I did it in other way but I must do it with help of Bisector planes and must get 2 answers.

Comment: My boek says CO(151/50,23/10,-98/50) or (-49/50,23/10,1/25)

Answer (score 0):

I would consider the following strategy:

1. Determine the normal vector n to the plane (Calculate (A-B) x (C-B)). Multiply by $\frac{\sqrt5}{|n|}$.
2. Find a point $\tilde{P}$ on the plane ABC that has equal distance from A,B and C. You can do so by intersecting the medians to $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{BC}$.
3. $P=\tilde{P}+n\frac{\sqrt5}{|n|}$

Comment: Isn’t there any way to solve it with Bisector planes https://etc.usf.edu/clipart/42100/42128/dihedralbis_42128_lg.gif